# In Compose how can I click on a IconButton at the screen level to execute a ViewModel method owned by a Composable at nested level?

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

The screen of my App is a Scaffold with a topBar (CenterAlignedTopAppBar), a content (NavHost) and a bottomBar (NavigationBar).
The NavigationBar allows to switch the Composable inside the NavHost.
Every Composable that can be inside the NavHost has different fields and its own ViewModel.
The CenterAlignedTopAppBar has a IconButton in the actions that I want to use to save the data in the current Composable inside the NavHost.
How can I handle the click on the IconButton (Scaffold level) to notify the current Composable inside the NavHost that it has to save its data by executing a method of its own ViewModel?
I do not want to keep all the ViewModels at the screen level.
In the old View System, the Fragment can contribute to the menu items in the Activity Menu: can I do something like that in Compose?
Any idea?

Comment: You can have a state variable at the screen level and pass it to the screens. Then use that variable to call the respective viewmodel method. So whenever the IconButton is clicked, update the variable and the current screen viewmodel method will be called.

Comment: @AjayChandran, So I have to use the state variable as a key for a LaunchedEffect in each subscreen and each LaunchedEffect can execute a method of the right ViewModel. Do I understand?

Comment: Not necessarily. Have the state variable in the main screen and just pass its value to the sub screens. Whenever the state is updated with new value, the sub screen method will be called and it will be smart recomposed with only the parameters that is changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the approach that you mentioned passing a key into all Composables and then using `LaunchedEffect` to observe changes is the cleanest approach. You can pass in a Boolean and flip it when you want to trigger a save:

```
@Composable
ParentWithScaffold() {
    //...
    var saveTrigger by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    IconButton(onClick = { saveTrigger = !saveTrigger }) {
        //...
    }
}

@Composable
fun Child(saveTrigger: Boolean, /*...*/) {
    LaunchedEffect(saveTrigger) {
        viewModel.save()
    }
}
```

---

You could however also use a function inside a function and pass that to the child Composable like this:

```
@Composable
fun ParentWithScaffold() {
    var triggerSave by remember { mutableStateOf<() -> Unit>({}) }

    // Initialize the trigger function inside the child composable
    Child(setTrigger = { trigger ->
        triggerSave = trigger  // get the save function set from within child
    })

    IconButton(onClick = triggerSave) {  // call save function of child
        //...
    }
}

@Composable
fun Child(setTrigger: (saveFunction: () -> Unit) -> Unit) {
    // Expose saveFunction to the parent
    val saveFunction: () -> Unit = {
        // call your ViewModel save() function here
    }
    //...
}
```

You set the actual ViewModel save function as the inner function in the child. That function then is accessible by the parent. Whenever the parent now calls `triggerSave()`, the child's save function will be executed.

Beware that this contradicts the [unidirectional data flow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf) (UDF) pattern that is used in Jetpack Compose. Usually, only data should flow downwards, and only events should flow upwards. That's why I think the `LaunchedEffect` approach would be cleaner.